# Using MVC3/EF CodeFirst with Repository Pattern, want to add sample data, getting error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, repository

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add sample data to an MVC3 application that uses EF Code First. I've pasted my sample code below as well as the error I'm getting.  Is there a good pattern to follow for adding sample data?

Any ideas appreciated.

```
 public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(usersRepository.GetAllUsers());
    }

    public ViewResult PopulateData()
    {
        PopulateUsersDb();

        return View(usersRepository.GetAllUsers());
    }

    private void PopulateUsersDb()
    {
        Users user1 = new Users()
        {
            CreationDate = DateTime.Today,
            Id = 1001,
            FirstName = "David",
            LastName = "Nadler",
            PlanExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6),
            Username = "dnadler"
        };
        usersRepository.InsertOrUpdate(user1);
        usersRepository.Save();
```

Error:

> Store update, insert, or delete
>   statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have
>   been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. Refresh
>   ObjectStateManager entries.

Comment: I think the interesting part is implementation of `InsertOrUpdate` method which is not shown in your question.

Comment: Agreed. The error means that it didn't do anything, which is what would happen if it *thinks* that it should do an update but the record doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.. repository pattern with ef code first. Maybe it can help you out.
http://average-uffe.blogspot.com/2011/03/repository-pattern-with-ef-code-first.html